# ¿Como hago para que me quede bien posicionado un submenu que le agregue a mi nav?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un nav_copy.php (que es donde estoy haciendo las pruebas) que le agregue esta linea de código:

```
'<div class="item-option">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a>'.$_SESSION['nomusu'].'</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>';
```

Mi problema es que el `<li><a>'.$_SESSION['nomusu'].'</a>` me queda abajo del nav y he intentado todo lo que sé y no se como hacer que quede a  la misma altura que los demás estilos. También otro problema es que el logo de carrito de compras se ve mas pequeño y no tengo idea por que.

Este es el código de mi nav completo:

```
<header>
    
        <div class="logo-place"><a href="index.php"><img src="assets/logo.png"></a></div>
        <div class="search-place">
            <input type="text" id="idbusqueda" placeholder="Encuenta todo lo que necesitas...">
            <button class="btn-main btn-search"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="options-place">
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['codusu'])) {
                echo
                '<div class="item-option">
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a>'.$_SESSION['nomusu'].'</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Salir</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </div>';
            }else{
            ?>
            <div class="item-option" title="Registrate"><i class="fa-solid fa-registered"></i></i></div>
            <div class="item-option" title="Ingresar"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="item-option" title="Mis compras">
                <a href="carrito.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </header>
```

Y estas son las lineas de codigo CSS con las que le doy estilo a mi nav

```
.options-place{
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    
    
}
.item-option{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    
}
.item-option a{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}
.nav{
    width:60px;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav > li {
    float:left;
}

.nav li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
}

.nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

.nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
}
```

PD: Este nav_copy.php lo estoy referenciando desde mi index.html, desde allí también referencio el head.php que es donde se referencia al index.css.

Asi es como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por defecto, las listas y sus elementos tienen margen interno (padding) o externo (margin), trata de ajustarlos, tanto para `.nav` como para `.nav > li`

Comment: Excelente apreciación me funciono.